# How to fix "hdfs://192.123.81.123:9000/atos/sample.pdf not a SequenceFile"

Tags: java, apache-spark, pdf, hdfs

Hello I'm starting with Apache Spark and 
I encountered a problem reading PDF from HDFS

I have tried solve my problem by using binary File, but i don't know how to implement that, all examples are wrote in scala language. I heard that Apache Tika provides PDF reading from binary files, but as long as i don't know how to read this pdf file, this knowlage is useless, now i'm using PDFBox

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-AI").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        JavaRDD<File> pdfFiles = javaSparkContext.objectFile("hdfs://192.123.81.123:9000/atos/sample.pdf");
        JavaRDD<PDDocument> pdfDocuments = a.map(file -> PDDocument.load(file));
        JavaRDD<String> pdfText = pdfDocuments.map(document -> new PDFTextStripper().getText(document));
```

Actual output is "java.io.IOException: hdfs://192.123.81.123:9000/atos/sample.pdf not a SequenceFile"

Comment: Please include the stack trace, and clarify on what line of the code above this is thrown. I think the exception does not come from PDFBox. And what is `a`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using .binaryFile(path) method, which return JavaPairRDD

Comment: `JavaSparkContext` class does not have a `binarySearch` method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html  Maybe you mean `binaryFiles`?